# Difficulties to close a "Ext.window.Window" in InternetExplorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, internet-explorer-9

I have a custom window created with ExtJs 4 and I found some difficulties to close it using the internet explorer 9. I try to close the window using the x button in the right top of the window and the majority of times it doesn't work. It works fine in chrome and firefox.
Here is the code:

```
Ext.define('Mainstay.view.import.Window', {
   extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
   alias : 'widget.importWindow',
   title: 'Import Records',
   layout:'fit',
   height: 590,
   width: 900,
   modal: true,
   autoload: true,

   initComponent: function(){
       this.callParent(arguments);
   }
});
```

Comment: sounds like a bug, you should probably report that to Sencha and mention your exact extjs version.

Comment: I've tested your code on ie9, using both 4.0.7 and 4.1.2 and the window closes every time. Can you install firebug light, and see if you are getting an error there?